# Large Volume Async Calls Being Blocked on Server

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous

I have an application that must send hundreds to thousands of HTTP requests at once. It's a .NET Windows service that uses Async calls. When my main server sends out small batches (around 1000 or less at a time) everything works fine, I get a response form the HTTP calls and all is good.

When it starts hitting 1500 or more at a time, though, all of sudden I get very little to no responses from my HTTP requests. When I run these large batch tests on my local machine though, I have no issues. Has anyone had any experience and might know what the culprit would be of what is holding back my .NET app?

Comment: Could it be a network bottleneck?

Comment: Do you also control the web service you're calling and the server on which it is running?  My guess (from the actual lack of responses) is that you're hitting some sort of quota meant to prevent degradation of quality of service from a single client sending too many requests in quick succession.

Comment: You need to be more specific about the kind of async calls you're doing.  Can you provide some examples of your code?  Different async calls work in different ways, and some use more resources than others.

Answer (score 0):

Async calls end up using ThreadPool behind the scenes. And creating a new thread for pool could be time consuming. Try to check ThreadPool.GetMaxThreads() to see how many threads can be created.

Another options is just your local machine is faster than server's one